# How to name a function(non-default image orientation)?

Tags: c++, interfaces, clean-code

I have a C++ interface for video provider. Frames can be rotated (Portrait/Landscape) as a result of platform-specific functions.

```
enum class EFrameOrientation
{
    KUp, // default orientation
    KDown,
    KLeft,
    KRight
};
```

Class gives the user info about orientation:

```
virtual EFrameOrientation getFrameOrientation() { return EFrameOrientation::KUp; }
```

Also it renders frames it owns with

```
virtual bool renderCurrentFrame() = 0;
virtual bool renderCurrentFrameWithOrientation() = 0; // STUB TO RENAME
```

and I added function that handles orientation issues, thus giving a user already `EFrameOrientation::KUp`-oriented frame.

Non-default orientation is not a bug, it can be desired in some cases. 
All below names seem semantically incorrect for me:

```
renderCurrentFrameRotated // doesn't say it's about orientation
renderCurrentFrameDefaultOriented // which orientation is default: KUp or current?
renderCurrentFrameOrientationFixed // its not bug to fix
```

How would you choose a good name in this case? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I like distinguishing such versions of things with the  "logical"/"physical" contrast. E.g. the headline might *logically* be at the top of the picture even though it is *physically* at the bottom because of rotation.

Comment: @KilianFoth Thanks! Then how about `renderCurrentFrame`? It's not an adjective to insert `logical`.

Comment: How does `renderCurrentFrameApplyingOrientation` sound?

Comment: @ViktorSeifert Sounds very good. :)

Comment: @Olia_Pavliuk, The distinction between the two methods would also become more clear when you add an `EFrameOrientation` argument to `renderCurrentFrameWithOrientation`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Clean Code guidelines method names should clearly state what the method is doing.  In this case we have a method which renders a frame but rotates the frame according to some orientation.  This rotation is a transformation of the frame.  Another term comes to my mind here: we're applying the transformation (rotation/orientation).

The way I understand the question is that it is possible for sub-classes to apply a different orientation, maybe even based on the instance not the class.  Therefore I think it would be misleading to include the type of the orientation in the method name.

So my recommendation is to call the method `renderCurrentFrameApplyingOrientation` since it clearly states that the method renders a frame and applies a transformation (the orientation in this case).  I also would recommend calling the other rendering method `renderCurrentFrameWithoutApplyingOrientation` to make it explicit that the frame will be rendered without applying the transformation.